# Tensorflow1 concat 2D tensors with all row wise permutations

Tags: python, tensorflow, concatenation, tensor

Let say we have two 2D tensors of shapes (`n, k`) and (`n, k`). We want to concat the two tensors with all row wise permutations such that the resulting tensor is of shape (`n, n, 2*k`).

Example,

```
A = [[a, b], [c, d]]; B = [[e, f], [g, h]]
```

The resulting tensor should be:

```
[[[a, b, e, f], [a, b, g, h]], [[c, d, e, f], [c, d, g, h]]]
```

Assume that the input tensors A and B have non-static shapes so we can not use for loop over `tf.shape()` indices value.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you need this to be done in TensorFlow or is Numpy/Pandas okay? This probably can be easily done in Pandas

Comment: I need this for TensorFlow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`tf.concat`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/concat) with [`tf.repeat`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/repeat) and [`tf.tile`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/tile)

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

# Input
A = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.array([['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]))
B = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.array([['e', 'f'], ['g', 'h']]))

# Repeat, tile and concat
C = tf.concat([tf.repeat(A, repeats=tf.shape(A)[-1], axis=0), 
               tf.tile(B, multiples=[tf.shape(A)[0], 1])], 
              axis=-1)

# Reshape to requested shape
C = tf.reshape(C, [tf.shape(A)[0], tf.shape(A)[0], -1])

print(C)

>>> <tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 2, 4), dtype=string, numpy=
>>> array([[[b'a', b'b', b'e', b'f'],
>>>         [b'a', b'b', b'g', b'h']],
>>>        [[b'c', b'd', b'e', b'f'],
>>>         [b'c', b'd', b'g', b'h']]], dtype=object)>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
A = np.array([['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']])
B = np.array([['e', 'f'], ['g', 'h']])

C = np.array([np.concatenate((a, b), axis=0) for a in A for b in B])
```

You can easily convert it to tensorflow like this

```
data =tf.convert_to_tensor(C, dtype=tf.string)
```

Output:

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(4, 4), dtype=string, numpy=
array([[b'a', b'b', b'e', b'f'],
       [b'a', b'b', b'g', b'h'],
       [b'c', b'd', b'e', b'f'],
       [b'c', b'd', b'g', b'h']], dtype=object)>
```

Not sure if the list comprehension part is the most efficient to do it for large data